# Markers are not showing up on my map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infobubble

I am trying to add markers according to events in a database and in the case of an event happening at the same location, adding a tab to the infoBubble for that new event. I can't seem to figure out why markers (and my infoBubbles) are not showing up on my map.

**Here is my code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDpQfirqx48owNbdu6ZF01pTr3Lt-tjYQI&sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobubble/src/infobubble.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

 var location_icon = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../images/FAFSA_Logo_icon.png');  
 var map;
 var markersArray= [];
 var infobubblesArray = [];
  function load() {

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.961586, -106.008728),
        zoom: 6,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
    });



    downloadUrl("../site_parts/mapmysql.php", function(data) {
    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var name = markers[i].getAttribute("event_name");
        var address = markers[i].getAttribute("venue_address");
        var city = markers[i].getAttribute("venue_city");
        var state = markers[i].getAttribute("venue_state");
        var zip = markers[i].getAttribute("venue_zip");
        var website = markers[i].getAttribute("venue_website");

        var date = markers[i].getAttribute("event_date");
        var start_time = markers[i].getAttribute("event_start_time");
        var end_time = markers[i].getAttribute("event_end_time");
        var room = markers[i].getAttribute("event_room");
        var cord = markers[i].getAttribute("ec_fname") + " " + markers[i].getAttribute("ec_lname");
        var cord_email = markers[i].getAttribute("ec_email");
        var cord_pnumber = markers[i].getAttribute("ec_pnumber");
        var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("venue_lat")),
            parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("venue_lng")));
        var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address +", "+ city +", "+ state +", "+ zip + "<br/>" +"<b>Date </b> "+ date +"<br/>" +"<b>Time </b> "+ start_time + " - "+ end_time +"<br/>" + "<b>Room </b>" + room + "<br/>"+ "<b> Cordinator </b>" + cord + " " + "<a href='mailto:" + cord_email + "?Subject=FAFSA%20FFA%20Event'>" + cord_email + "</a> " + cord_pnumber;
        var icon =  location_icon;

            for (var x = 0; x < markersArray.length; x++){
                if (markersArray[x].getPosition() == point){
                    infobubblesArray[x].addTab(date, html);
                    break;
                }  
                if (x < (markersArray.length -1)){continue} else{
                    var newM = x+1;
                    markersArray[newM] = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: point, icon: icon});
                    infobubbleArray[newM] = new InfoBubble({maxWidth: 400, borderWidth: 2});
                    bindinfoBubble(markersArray[newM], map, infobubblesArray[newM])
                    infobubblesArray[newM].addTab(date, html);
                  }
            }  
        }
    });
  }

function bindinfoBubble(marker, map, infoBubble) {
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

    infoBubble.open(map, marker);


  });
}

function downloadUrl(url,callback) {
 var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
    new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
    new XMLHttpRequest;

request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4) {
    request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
    callback(request, request.status);
    }
};

request.open('GET', url, true);
request.send(null);
}

function doNothing() {} 

</script>
```

**XML**

```
<markers>
<marker event_name="Atrisco Heritage Academy" venue_address="10800 Dennis Chavez             Boulevard" venue_city="Albuquerque" venue_state="New Mexico" venue_zip="87121"         venue_website="http://ahahighschool.com" venue_lat="35.022449" venue_lng="-106.748777"             event_date="2013-01-17" event_start_time="0" event_end_time="0" event_room="TBD" ec_fname="TBD" ec_lname="" ec_email="" ec_pnumber=""/>
<marker event_name="Bernalillo High School" venue_address="250 Isidro Sanchez Rd" venue_city="Bernalillo" venue_state="New Mexico" venue_zip="87004" venue_website="http://www.bernalillo.bps.k12.nm.us/education/school/school.php?sectionid=3" venue_lat="35.321560" venue_lng="-106.541828" event_date="2013-01-22" event_start_time="0" event_end_time="0" event_room="TBD" ec_fname="TBD" ec_lname="" ec_email="" ec_pnumber=""/>
<marker event_name="Bernalillo High School" venue_address="250 Isidro Sanchez Rd" venue_city="Bernalillo" venue_state="New Mexico" venue_zip="87004" venue_website="http://www.bernalillo.bps.k12.nm.us/education/school/school.php?sectionid=3" venue_lat="35.321560" venue_lng="-106.541828" event_date="2013-01-23" event_start_time="0" event_end_time="0" event_room="TBD" ec_fname="TBD" ec_lname="" ec_email="" ec_pnumber=""/>
<marker event_name="Cibola High School" venue_address="1510 Ellison Drive" venue_city="Albuquerque" venue_state="New Mexico" venue_zip="87114" venue_website="http://www.cibolacougars.com" venue_lat="35.205190" venue_lng="-106.663214" event_date="2013-01-23" event_start_time="0" event_end_time="0" event_room="TBD" ec_fname="TBD" ec_lname="" ec_email="" ec_pnumber=""/>
<marker event_name="Rio Rancho High School" venue_address="301 Loma Colorado N.E." venue_city="Rio Rancho" venue_state="New Mexico" venue_zip="87124" venue_website="http://rioranchohigh.rrps.net/" venue_lat="35.272536" venue_lng="-106.678116" event_date="2013-01-30" event_start_time="0" event_end_time="0" event_room="TBD" ec_fname="TBD" ec_lname="" ec_email="" ec_pnumber=""/>
<marker event_name="Farmington high School" venue_address="2200 Sunset Ave." venue_city="Farmington" venue_state="New Mexico" venue_zip="87401" venue_website="http://fhs.fms.k12.nm.us/" venue_lat="36.749957" venue_lng="-108.204563" event_date="2013-02-04" event_start_time="0" event_end_time="0" event_room="TBD" ec_fname="TBD" ec_lname="" ec_email="" ec_pnumber=""/>
<marker event_name="Cimarron High School" venue_address="165 North Collison Avenue" venue_city="Cimarron" venue_state="NM" venue_zip="87714" venue_website="http://www.chsrams.org/" venue_lat="36.512275" venue_lng="-104.920166" event_date="2013-02-04" event_start_time="0" event_end_time="0" event_room="TBD" ec_fname="TBD" ec_lname="" ec_email="" ec_pnumber=""/>
<marker event_name="West Mesa High School" venue_address="6701 Fortuna Road NW" venue_city="Albuquerque" venue_state="New Mexico" venue_zip="87121" venue_website="http://www.westmesamustangs.com" venue_lat="35.095882" venue_lng="-106.716171" event_date="2013-02-05" event_start_time="0" event_end_time="0" event_room="TBD" ec_fname="TBD" ec_lname="" ec_email="" ec_pnumber=""/>
</markers>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors logged in console?

Comment: none on the chrome console

Comment: I think it has something to do with for loop to test for locations on previous markers, but that's as far as I can figure.

Comment: Is your XML valid?  Can you open "../site_parts/mapmysql.php" in your web browser?  If it is valid, what is markers.length in your processing loop?

Comment: I can, it's valid. The pull from the database is right. markers.length gets longer as markers are added, but I'm not actually sure if the length is equal to the items in the array such as 2 for two items, or if its 1 for two items.

Comment: Try commenting out the icon:icon in the Marker constructor (so it uses the default marker icon), sounds like the markers might be there but not visible.

Comment: I commented that out with no change. I've been able to use that image in earlier iterations of this page

Comment: Certainly sounds like it should work.  Can you provide a link or a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem?  If not, do you have a sample of your XML that can be used for testing?

Comment: I added the xml I'm using as an update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that seems to be working (besides the tabs starting in a row above the current tabs) here is the ending loop to check for that:

```
var x = 0;

while (x < (markersArray.length)){
  if (markersArray[x].getPosition().toString() == point.toString()){
  infobubblesArray[x].addTab(date, html);
  continue xmlLoop; /*to the outside loop for the xml sheet readthrough*/
  }x++;
}

var newM = markersArray.length;
markersArray[newM] = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: point, icon: icon});
infobubblesArray[newM] = new InfoBubble({maxWidth: 500, minHight: 600, borderRadius: 0});
bindinfoBubble(markersArray[newM], map, infobubblesArray[newM]);
infobubblesArray[newM].addTab(date, html);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are different issues, most of all the `for (var x = 0; x < markersArray.length; x++)`

You create the markers inside this loop, but initially markersArray is empty, you will never run this loop. There is also a typo, `infobubbleArray` should be `infobubblesArray`

Fixed code:

```
downloadUrl("../site_parts/mapmysql.php", function(data) {

    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
    outer: for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

           /* creation of the variables may stay here as it is */

            for (var x = 0; x < markersArray.length; x++){
                if (markersArray[x].getPosition().toString() == point.toString()){
                    infobubblesArray[x].addTab(date, html);                         
                    continue outer;
                }}

                var newM = markersArray.length;
                    markersArray[newM] = new google.maps.Marker({map: map, position: point});
                    infobubblesArray[newM] = new InfoBubble({maxWidth: 400, borderWidth: 2});
                    bindinfoBubble(markersArray[newM], map, infobubblesArray[newM])
                    infobubblesArray[newM].addTab(date, html);
        }
    });
```

Comment: The reason I had the check before the second part of the for x loop was to make sure it checked all current markers for position, and if none matched then it would create a new marker but only if none where a match. I don't want a new marker created every time the loop runs.

Comment: That's exactly what my suggestion above does.